# Need help using varybycontrol

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am learning ASP.Net and I am trying to use OutputCache - varybycontrol based on tutorial like this:

```
<%@ OutputCache duration="15" varybyparam= "none" varybycontrol="txtName" %>
```

Somehow txtName which is my textbox doesn't get cache, without the varybycontrol it works fine for caching all controls in the form. Can someone please advice, thanks.

Comment: Okay sure, I wasn't aware of the 'tick' beside every reply until lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Master/content pages then VaryByControl won't work.

See explanation here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/465461/outputcache-varybycontrol-cannot-be-used-in-content-pages

Comment: I am not using it in a Master page, just a plain .aspx page.